# how to make if decision in swiftmailer to check if field is empty then do not send `td` to mail

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send email(s) after submitting a form, I want to achieve:

1) If field is empty then no need to send table row to mail. Just like the field `age` below is optional, user might add his/her age or might not, so how to do it in `switmail` `$message->addPart('Message','text/html')` function.

I tried but failed saying:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in...`
The issue is only with `if`.. without `if` statement everything works fine.

```
$content = '<table>
   ...
   <tr><td>' . $_POST["firstname"] . '<td></tr>
   ' . if(!empty($_POST["age"])) {
          . '<tr><td>' . $_POST["age"] . '</td></tr>' .
       }
     ...
<table>';
$message->addPart($content, 'text/html');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @Sharoon what is inside the $_POST[""] that you are using.   $_POST["$firstname"], is this in your code

Comment: no sorry I just wrote it wrong here.. going to edit it.

Comment: **stap** just stop ... and **RTFM**
you can't do an if in the middle of a concat.

you have to finish that string do the if and concat it after ;)

Comment: Please tell me more, I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it outside of the `$content` variable.

```
$age = (!empty($_POST["age"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["age"] . '</td></tr>' : '';

$content = '<table>
   ...
   <tr><td>' . $_POST["firstname"] . '<td></tr>'
   . $age . '
     ...
<table>';
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, You made me happy dude Excellent.

Comment: I'm facing same problem with `foreach`.. how to deal with that?