# PHP Form: If a input field is empty then do not send the table data to mail

Tags: javascript, php

Here this form will not only send mail to me but also a duplicate copy to the user.And what I want to achieve is:

1. The entered data should be sent to mail in Html Table Format.
2. If an input field is empty then that table data should not be sent to emails. I also referred this link: ([how to make if decision in swiftmailer to check if field is empty then do not send `td` to mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574112/how-to-make-if-decision-in-swiftmailer-to-check-if-field-is-empty-then-do-not-se)) but I didn't get this.

Note: I don't want all the fields to be required. Here I have given only name, email, and address fields as required in HTML, and the remaining fields are can be left empty and submit the form.

But for now, I am not getting any mail if I submit this form

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "...@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address

$from = (!empty($_POST["email"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["email"] . '</td></tr>' : '';
$name = (!empty($_POST["name"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["name"] . '</td></tr>' : '';
$address = (!empty($_POST["address"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["address"] . '</td></tr>' : '';

$book_shelf = (!empty($_POST["book_shelf"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["book_shelf"] . '</td></tr>' : '';
$glass_ware = (!empty($_POST["glass_ware"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["glass_ware"] . '</td></tr>' : '';
$speakers = (!empty($_POST["speakers"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["speakers"] . '</td></tr>' : '';
$carpets = (!empty($_POST["carpets"])) ? '<tr><td>' . $_POST["carpets"] . '</td></tr>' : '';


$content = '<table>'.$name.$from.$address.$book_shelf.$glass_ware.$speakers.$carpets.'</table>';


$content2 = '<table>'.$name.$address.$book_shelf.$glass_ware.$speakers.$carpets.'</table>';


$headers = "From:" . $from;
$subject = "Form submission";

$headers2 = "From:" . $to;  
$subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
?>
```

```js
function add(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id),
    value = +element.value || 0;
  element.value = value + 1;
}

function sub(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id),
    value = +element.value || 0;
  value--;
  if (value < 0) {
    value = 0;
  }
  element.value = value;
}
```

```html
HTML Code:

<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter E-Mail" name="email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="Address" name="address" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="range-label">
      <label>Book Shelf</label>
    </div>
    <div class="range">
      <a onClick="sub('book-shelf')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><input type="text" id="book-shelf" name="book_shelf"><a onClick="add('book-shelf')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <!--start-->
    <div class="range-label">
      <label>Glass Ware</label>
    </div>
    <div class="range">
      <a onClick="sub('glass-ware')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><input type="text" id="glass-ware" name="glass_ware"><a onClick="add('glass-ware')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end-->

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <!--start-->
    <div class="range-label">
      <label>Speakers</label>
    </div>
    <div class="range">
      <a onClick="sub('speakers')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><input type="text" id="speakers" name="speakers"><a onClick="add('speakers')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end-->


  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <!--start-->
    <div class="range-label">
      <label>Carpets</label>
    </div>
    <div class="range">
      <a onClick="sub('Carpets')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><input type="text" id="Carpets" name="carpets"><a onClick="add('Carpets')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end-->

  </div>
  <!--    End of row --->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You could start with adding [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) to your inputs

Comment: No, i don't want all the fields to be required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the required values are set and are not empty, if they are set, then send the email.

You will need to set its headers so that it can be sent as HTML and not plain text. Also, [here](https://pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support/) is a list of supported tags in an email template

```
//Set headers
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html';
$headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html';

if(
   isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"] != "" &&
   isset($_POST["name"]) && $_POST["name"] != "" &&
   isset($_POST["address"]) && $_POST["address"] != ""
  )
  {
    // If all required fields are set, then email them
    mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$content2,$headers2);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
  }
```

Comment: Here i want this data to be sent to my mail in HTML table format. How to do that?

Comment: @manjeshwars You just need to change the variables. I have updated my answer, take a look

Comment: I have changed the variables and it showing mail sent. But i haven't received any mail.

Comment: @manjeshwars Did you check your spam folder? Also, are you running this code on a local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Add HTML  required Attribute to your input fields as following example

```js
function myFunction() {

  var name = document.getElementById("usrname").value;
  var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

  if (city) {
    alert(name + " " + city)

  } else {
    alert(name)

  }


}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Name: <input type="text" id="usrname" required><br> City: <input type="text" id="city"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Here I don't want all the fields to be required

Comment: set required in fields you want in my example city is not required

Comment: In your code if i submit the form i will get the output to my mail as: Name:My name, City:

Comment: But if the field is left blank it should not be sent to my mail. In your code If city is left blank, it should not send that text city to my mail

Comment: you handle it using js or back-end

Comment: Here I am using PHP

Comment: it is better if you can handle validation in front end use js

Comment: It is BEST to handle validation BOTH front end and back end

Comment: Here i want this data to be sent to my mail in HTML table format

Comment: @mplungjan agreed